# c++ vector size and capacity outputting same value

Tags: c++, string, stdvector

when I was researching vectors, I noticed that `size()` is supposed to give the number of elements in the vector, right? So, when I found c++ does not have a string `split()` function built-in, I decided to make one. The problem is, `vector.size()` displays the same value as `vector.capacity()` as shown in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void split(string input, char chr, vector<string> list) {
    string add;
    string conv;
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= input.size(); i++) {
        if ((input[i] != char(chr)) && (input[i] != 0)) {
            conv = input[i];
            add += conv;
        }
        else {
            cout << list.size() << endl;
            if (size <= list.capacity()) {
                list[size] = add;
                add = "";
                size++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<string> list(6);
    split("test1,test2", ',', list);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
6
6
<blank line>
<blank line>
```

whereas it SHOULD be this from my understanding:

```
1
2
test1
test2
```

Edit: if this is of any importance, I am compiling with -std=c++11

Comment: Remarks on the code: You are using `std::string` so you should include `<string>`; the same for `<vector>`; "`list`" is probably a bad name for a variable (especially a vector), especially with a global `using namespace std;`; your `split` function takes a vector _by value_, so the `list[size] = add;` only modifies a local _copy_ of the vector defined in `main`, is it really what you want? (if not, then take the vector by reference: `void split(/*...*/, vector<string>& list) { /*...*/ }`).

Comment: Also `i <= input.size()` should probably be `i < input.size()`, and `size <= list.capacity()` is suspect.

Comment: yeah, i looked up that i needed to use &, and no I need to use `i <= list.capacity()` because when it gets to the last letter, there won't be anything to flush out the last contents of `add` into `list[size]`  (by triggering `input[i] == 0`) unless if I put it outside the for loop which I very well may do now that I think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize the vector with size 6, not capacity 6. It will be constructed with 6 empty elements inside and thus setting values 0 and 1 won't change that.

The reason why you see only blank lines is that you pass the vector by value instead of by reference to you split function.

Comment: how can I initialize the vector with a size of 6 in this case and not 6 empty elements? I had a feeling this is what was happening, but I'm not aware of any other way to do it. Also, how am I able to pass it via reference?

Comment: Use [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void split (const std::string& s, char sep, std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    if (s.empty()) return;
    std::size_t beg = 0;
    std::size_t end = s.find(sep, beg);

    while (end != std::string::npos)
    {
        words.push_back(s.substr(beg, end - beg));
        beg = end + 1;
        end = s.find(sep, beg);
    }
    words.push_back(s.substr(beg));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    split("test1,test2", ',', words);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != words.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << words[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this probably works (I didn't test it but I suppose that you did), but wouldn't the code deserve a bit of explanation? (Also, why rename `split` to `Split`, why use `std::` for `vector` and `string` but not `size_t`, where are the `#include`s?)